# 'Could not MERGE resource' 500 Error with 'Can't set position pointer in file' and 'Access is denied'

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet

Users get this error when they try to commit to the repo with a pre-commit hook in place. The pre-commit hook checks if the user should be able to commit and if the commit message is formatted correctly using `svnlook.exe` and `--transaction`. The logs show the following:

```
[Mon Dec 05 08:35:06.073768 2016] [dav:error] [pid 4780:tid 816] [client xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx]
    Could not MERGE resource "/svn/SOME_REPO/!svn/txn/499-ei" into "/svn/SOME_REPO/trunk/    RESTRICTED/SomeFolder/AnotherFolder".  [500, #0]
[Mon Dec 05 08:35:06.074768 2016] [dav:error] [pid 4780:tid 816] [client xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx]
    An error occurred while committing the transaction.  [500, #720005]
[Mon Dec 05 08:35:06.074768 2016] [dav:error] [pid 4780:tid 816] [client xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] Can't set position pointer in file 
    '\\\\zzzvnxnas01.zzz.com\\zzz\\Projects\\ZZZZ1SVSUBVML1\\CSVN\\Repositories\\SOME_REPO\\db\\txn-protorevs\\499-ei.rev': Access is denied.    [500, #720005]
```

---

I currently don't have access to the server so I need to diagnose it from the bits and pieces I do have. Subversion is ~1.8 running on Apache ~2.4 on CollabNet SubversionEdge.

My guess is that `svnlook` is causing problems from the service not having enough permission because when the pre-commit hook is removed, users report no errors. Also, is it possible for that service to get overloaded?

The only problem with my theory is that there are no issues on the dev server... `:D`

Otherwise, I think it may have to do with generally corrupted users' files that require `svn cleanup`, incompatible program versions interacting amongst themselves, anti-virus sticking its nose in, user load on the production server, or some network permissions issue.

Anyone have any experience in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that `svnlook` has anything do with that.

The error says "Access is denied":

```
Can't set position pointer in file 
    '\\\\zzzvnxnas01.zzz.com\\zzz\\Projects\\ZZZZ1SVSUBVML1\\CSVN\\Repositories\\SOME_REPO\\db\\txn-protorevs\\499-ei.rev': Access is denied.
```

The account that runs your server does not have enough permissions to the repositories. An antivirus could also be the root cause as it could block the write operation.

Comment: I believe the Collabnet Svn Edge/Server are both Local System accounts, so that rules out the permissions possibility, right? Or could there be another account that handles repo duties?

Comment: I'm fairly new to all of this, but I'm going to guess that yes, it's on a network share.

Comment: @moogle make sure that all the necessary NTFS and share permissions were set on the network share for the computer account where your server runs. http://serverfault.com/a/135874/107134

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. However, do you have any ideas why removing code (that calls svnlook) from my pre-commit hook 'fixes' the issue?